# Change folder name in webapp when deployin in Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I have a project named "test-xxx" in eclipse. 
When i choose `Run as > Run on server`, a "test-xxx" folder is created in tomcat webapps folder.
I want to change this folder name to deploy my project in a "test" folder, not "test-xxx", and keeping the possibility to debug/publish my application. 
This project is very particular and I can't rename it in eclipse.

Maybe i can make a SYMLINK "test" that point to "test-xxx", but whith this hack, I need tell to tomcat to not deploy the folder "test-xxx", only test

Do you have any tips for doing this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

In Project Properties, go to Web Project Settings and change the context root to the prefix you want; it's auto-populated with the project name.

Comment: When i do it, i can acces my projet from http://localhost:8080/test, but it still beeing deployed to webapps/test-xxx ...

Comment: You want to do that for your copy of tomcat that you run from within eclipse, or for the final deployment?

Comment: For my tomcat run from Eclipse, not the final deployment (cf. `[...] and keeping the possibility to debug/publish my application`)

Comment: Ah, open the server configuration (double-click on the server), go to modules, select your module and click edit; this allows you to set the folder name up.

Comment: With this module view, I can add a module, but i can edit the "Document Base" field. So I tried to edit the server.xml, and I changed my conf like that : `<Context docBase="test" path="/test" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:test-xxx"/>`. Nothing happen, exept an error on the module view telling me : `The Web module at the following location cannot be found: test`

Comment: (edit: can -> can't from prev post ) : `but i can't edit the "Document Base" field `

Comment: Ah, you have an issue then; you could just create the symlink, but Tomcat will use that as a 2nd application...